# Xwidget error. "Symbol’s value as variable is void: xwidget-webkit-enable-plugins

Tags: mu4e

I compiled Homebrew Emacs-Plus (28.1), with xwidget support.  Using doom emacs. I'm trying to get mu4e to run with xwidgets (mu4e-views).

I get the following error when trying to run `(xwidget-webkit-browse-url)`:

> xwidget-insert: Symbol’s value as variable is void: xwidget-webkit-enable-plugins

It is a little inconsistent. Sometimes xwidget loads, and I can get emails and the browser to load correctly. But every so often, I get a blank window that can only be closed by killling the buffer.

I have found no help with this particular error error elsewhere. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved it! Found the solution here: https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/whats-new-in-emacs-28-1

> New user option 'xwidget-webkit-enable-plugins'. If non-nil, enable
> plugins in xwidget.  (This is only available on macOS.)

I added a

`(setq xwidget-webkit-enable-plugins 't)`

Seems to work now.